# PHP/Codeigniter Logical Operator

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$total_cost_for_A = $this->admin_model->total_cost_for_A($branch, $department, $date);
$total_cost_for_B = $this->admin_model->total_cost_for_B($branch, $department, $date);
```

The variables *$total_cost_for_A and $total_cost_for_B*  hold the returned value from a mysql summation queries in the model. The queries return false if no record was found. Now, I'm trying to perform this operation.

```
if(($total_cost_for_A === FALSE) && ($total_cost_for_B === FALSE))
{
  $data['no_record'] = 'No Record Found!';
  $this->load->view('admin/bookings', $data);
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('admin/summary', $data);
}
```

This test always fail and execute the else statement instead, which is not what. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks

**Here are the functions**

```
    function total_cost_for_A($branch, $department, $date)
    {
        if($branch == 'Head Office' && $department == 'Summary')
        {
            $select_amount_paid = 'SELECT SUM(total_amount) total_amount FROM graphics_booking AS bk
            WHERE bk.date = "'.$date.'"';
        }

        $result = $this->db->query($select_amount_paid);

        if($result->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }


    function total_cost_for_B($branch, $department, $date)
    {
        if($branch == 'Head Office' && $department == 'Summary')
        {
            $total_LF_amount = 'SELECT SUM(total_amount) total_amount FROM large_format_print
            WHERE date = "'.$date.'"';
        }

        $result = $this->db->query($total_LF_amount);

        if($result->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you `var_dump` total_cost_A and B to make sure of the types they are returning.

Comment: yes, i just did and it returns an empty object.

Comment: Post your `total_cost_for_A()` and `total_cost_for_B()` functions.

Answer (score 3):

Empty objects are not false.

As for your comment, please make sure that `total_cost_for_A`
and `B` are actually returning something.  And make sure that they are returning `false` on failure.  That is the only way your conditional will evaluate to true.

You are using strict equality comparison so they will never equal false unless you return `false`!

`if(($total_cost_for_A == FALSE) && ($total_cost_for_B == FALSE))`

The above should work because empty arrays are false.

Comment: I use the strict equality because false will be the returned value from the query if nothing is found in the database. Actually $total_cost_for_A and $total_cost_for_B are to return false when a user search for records with a date that is not already in the database. I don't know if my explanation is clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your comparisons need to use $total_cost_**for**_A and $total_cost_**for**_B

you are missing "for" from your variable names.

Comment: Thanks that was a typo, but problem still there