# Codeigniter logical operator

Tags: codeigniter

I ask the question before I was not getting anymore replies and I decide to re-post it if that will help. I hope i'm not doing anything wrong by re-posting?

```
$total_cost_for_A = $this->admin_model->total_cost_for_A($branch, $department, $date);
$total_cost_for_B = $this->admin_model->total_cost_for_B($branch, $department, $date);
```

The variables *$total_cost_for_A and $total_cost_for_B*  hold the returned value from a mysql summation queries in the model. The queries return false if no record was found. Now, I'm trying to perform this operation.

```
if(($total_cost_for_A === FALSE) && ($total_cost_for_B === FALSE))
{
  $data['no_record'] = 'No Record Found!';
  $this->load->view('admin/bookings', $data);
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('admin/summary', $data);
}
```

This test always fail and execute the else statement instead, which is not what. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks

**Here are the functions**

```
    function total_cost_for_A($branch, $department, $date)
    {
        if($branch == 'Head Office' && $department == 'Summary')
        {
            $select_amount_paid = 'SELECT SUM(total_amount) total_amount FROM graphics_booking AS bk
            WHERE bk.date = "'.$date.'"';
        }

        $result = $this->db->query($select_amount_paid);

        if($result->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }


    function total_cost_for_B($branch, $department, $date)
    {
        if($branch == 'Head Office' && $department == 'Summary')
        {
            $total_LF_amount = 'SELECT SUM(total_amount) total_amount FROM large_format_print
            WHERE date = "'.$date.'"';
        }

        $result = $this->db->query($total_LF_amount);

        if($result->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are. Be patient. @dm03514 gave a great answer. Please solve this [in the other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323539/php-codeigniter-logical-operator). Flagged to close.

Comment: someone should take it down. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this

```
 $select_amount_paid = 'SELECT SUM(total_amount) total_amount FROM graphics_booking AS bk
        WHERE date = '.$date;//i assume that date is an colum from graphics_booking
```

you are wrong with "bk.date" you can give directly if it is in your table with where condition and also try to avoid the same name for the function in the model and the varaible assigned.Try to change as different.otherwise your code looks good

Answer (score 0):

No when u return u cannot return the entire , you need to return a row

so you need to do in your model as :

```
 function total_cost_for_A($branch, $department, $date)
    {
        if($branch == 'Head Office' && $department == 'Summary')
        {
            $select_amount_paid = 'SELECT SUM(total_amount) total_amount FROM graphics_booking AS bk
            WHERE bk.date = "'.$date.'"';
        }

        $result = $this->db->query($select_amount_paid);

        if($result->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $result->row();     // you missed out here
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Same for the total_cost_for_B()

Comment: @sality im hoping you have run the query in mysql and its running fine